# play 2 get url parameter in filter

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

how to get url parameter in Filter

routes

```
GET        /:lang/               controllers.SiteIndex.index(lang)
GET        /:lang/genres/        controllers.Genres.allGenres(lang)
```

Global

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    val a = request.getQueryString("lang")
    val b = request.getQueryString("language")
    println("executed before every request:" + request.toString)
    super.onRouteRequest(request)
  }
}
```

how to get parameter lang in Global and set language in all actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that would be easier using a custom action builder, since onRouteRequest cannot affect what parameters are passed to you actions. You could get something like:

```
def myAction = ActionWithLang { req: MyCustomReqWithLang => 
   ...
   Ok("woo " + req.myLang)
}
```

Look at the play docs under action composition for more info about this:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: there is a posibility get url parameter in request like this  
object LocaleController extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
    request.getParameter("locale") 
    block(request)
  }
}

Comment: Exactly, ActionWithLang would be easiest constructed using an ActionBuilder